# Как записать словарь в excel файл Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, excel, beautiful-soup

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS 
import csv


def get_html(url):
    session = requests.session()
    session.headers = {'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}
    r = session.get(url)
    if r.ok:
        return r.text
    else:
        print(r.status_code)


def write_csv(data):
    with open('realtytrac.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow((data['adress'],
                        data['url'],
                        data['price'],
                        data['date']))

def fix_price(text):
    price = text.split('$')
    price = price[1].replace(',', '')
    return price

def fix_date(text):
    date = text.split(' ')
    date = date[3]
    return date


def get_page_data(html, url):
    soup = BS(html, 'lxml')

    try:
        adress = soup.find('section', class_='summary-block').find('h1')
        adresses = adress.find_all('span')
        adress = adresses[0].text + ' ' + adresses[1].text + ' ' + adresses[2].text + ' ' + adresses[3].text
    except:
        adress = ''

    try:
        prices = soup.find('div', class_='price').find('strong').text
        price = fix_price(prices)
    except:
        price = ''

    try:
        dates = soup.find('div', class_='col-3').find('a').text.strip()
        date = fix_date(dates)
    except:
        date = ''

    data = {'adress': adress,
            'url': url,
            'price': price,
            'date': date}

    write_csv(data)



def main():
#   url = 'https://www.realtytrac.com/propertydetails/pa/tarentum/15084/johnson-ave/109435477/'
    url = input('Введите ссылку: ')
    get_page_data(get_html(url), url)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вот парсер, данные записываю в словарь data, и затем словарь передается в функцию write_csv, которая записывает все это в файл csv. Но мне нужно чтобы записывалось в файл excel (нужно использовать библиотеку openpyxl как я понял),но я так и не понял как это сделать. Чтобы все было хорошо, каждый элемент словаря, отдельный столбик, ну как это все в csv записалось красиво, так и в excel надо. Но я не знаю как, можете пример показать, а я уже потом запомню, заранее спасибо.

Comment: А почему вы не хотите просто открыть потом csv файл в Excel-е? )

Comment: Посмотрите лучше в сторону `pandas`, где можно [как читать csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), так и [сохранять в excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

Comment: @CrazyElf ну там как то не так отображается это все. Просто в строчку через запятую идут данные, не по колонкам, а как то несуразно

Comment: @PustovoyAndrei Наверное, в `Excel` другой символ разделения колонок, например `;`, надо тогда в `csv` писать с тем разделителем, который понимается Excel-ем, т.е. `writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужа только запись словаря в *.csv, нет необходимости в openpyxl. Проще через pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
di = {
    "кг":[1,2,3],
    "слова":["сала","мало","мама"]
     }
z = pd.DataFrame(di)
z.to_excel("file_name.xlsx")
```

и результат будет таким:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем случае ведущие индексы (первый столбец) видимо не нужны, тогда последний оператор пишите так:

```
z.to_excel("file_name.xlsx", index=False)
```

Ну или как советовали товарищи, использовать в вашем коде разделитель не "," а ***";"***:

```
def write_csv(data):
with open('realtytrac.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
    writer.writerow((data['adress'],
                    data['url'],
                    data['price'],
                    data['date']))
```